# Loading configurational data during page load in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, splash-screen

I'm working on a React application that is connected to a few ASP.NET Core WebAPI microservices. Each of these services have different entities that are used throughout the application.
Within the complete application, there are enums and 'configurational data' that can be configured.
Imagine configurational data as just simple tables, with two fields (Id and Value).

Different entities have FK relationships to the configurational data, and/or have enum fields. I'm trying to understand how I would, in a performant way, can load the configurational data and all the used enums upfront upon page load, so that these can be used in dropdowns. I'm pretty new to React (1 month), so still learning day by day.

I've initially taken the approach of writing a custom DropDown component that accepts a WebAPI GET url, to fetch the possible values for a certain table or enum, but it's very impractical and will prove to be not so performant once there are 1000 users using the application, and all doing calls to these api's multiple times, just for some dropdowns.

So, what is the advised approach to have some sort of splash screen in React AND call APIs to cache values, that then can be used in other components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"I've initially taken the approach of writing a custom DropDown component that accepts a WebAPI GET url"*

You should not do this :)

Before I suggest a solution I want to go through a couple of important key concepts.

**Firstly**

The render method will always run once before you async stuff happens (like your GET).

Lifecycle methods order which will trigger the  *First Render* :  `constructor` => `componentWillMount` => `render` => `componentDidMount`.

This means that you will have to have all your data ready for render initially. Or have conditions which prevents certain `jsx` for being called.

**Secondly**

If you have dynamic content, which will be the options in your dropdown, you'll have to get it from somewhere. *If it's static you can define a list locally.* 
If you want to save the response you could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) or if you are using redux; the middleware [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to persist the store.

I personally don't see the purpose though, because if the dynamic options updates you would want that to update the application state. And even 1000 simple calls like that is not expensive for the server.

If you are using redux, you should keep the options there, because then you won't have to make an `GET` every time you're mounting the component with the dropdown.

**Suggestion:**

*Many ways you can do this but here is a simple solution)*.

keep a local state in component and initialize it for first render 
`this.state = {dropDownOptions: []}`

Then in `componentDidMount` make api call:

`fetch(url).then((response)=>this.setState({dropDownOptions: response}));`

And lastly in your render method:

`<MyDropDown options={this.state.dropDownOptions} .../>`

Comment: Just to give you a heads-up; I've started investigating Redux and learning how to use it, and now I've configured a store with seperate reducers for some 'configurational' data that are cached upon initial app load and can be used everywhere, without additional fetches. Thanks for the tip!